# Android: Unable to resolve dependency

Tags: java, android, dependencies

I'm new to using Android Studio and basically I'm having problem with my dependencies I've tried upgrading my gradle plugin version to 3.5.1 and my gradle version to 5.4.1 and still nothing happened. I basically have 2 projects in my workspace one is the nerarosbridgeclient which is my library and the robot utility which is my main application..

here is my ERROR:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':robotutility@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :nerarosbridgeclient.
Unable to find a matching configuration of project :nerarosbridgeclient:
- None of the consumable configurations have attributes. Could not resolve 
  project :nerarosbridgeclient. Required by: project :robotutility Caused 
 by:org.gradle.internal.component.NoMatchingConfigurationSelectionException: 
 Unable to find a matching configuration of project :nerarosbridgeclient:
```

- None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

My build.gradle(Project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

  buildscript {
      repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
      }
   }

 allprojects {
    repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()

    }
 }

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir

   }
```

My build.gradle(Module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.nerarobotics.robotutility'
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
     }
 }

  dependencies {
//noinspection DuplicatePlatformClasses
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

implementation 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
implementation project(path: ':nerarosbridgeclient')
}
```

And my settings.gradle

```
include ':robotutility', ':nerarosbridgeclient'
```

my LIBRARY build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 29
  buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"


defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-rules.pro'
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
 optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
     }

   }

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
implementation 'com.neovisionaries:nv-websocket-client:2.9'
}

  buildscript {
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add more build log to question. It will help.

Comment: have you tried with only implementation project(':nerarosbridgeclient')

Comment: @SebastienRieu just tried doing it. but still same error occurred

Comment: @YenBico can you please add `build.gradle` file for that library project as well.

Comment: @ShadowDroid sorry for the late reply. I have added the gradle for that library in the question. thanks!